# List all running notebooks on jupyter server

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I want to write a script to list all the .ipynb notebook files that are running on my jupyter server http://localhost:40000/tree/.

I am unable to find a command to do so, however i can only find command that lists all running servers:

```
jupyter notebooks list
```

Please list any method / shell command to do so.

Comment: 2021 and still looking for a solution to this ...